# Retrieve facebook data in backend service

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, service, backend

I'm currently working on an app (iOS 6) where the user will be signing in using their facebook account. 
In regards to this I have a few questions:

a) Since the app asks the user for permission to access cetain data (like: basic profile info, friend list, access to post to wall etc), I assume that the app based on it's app id will be somehow authenticated to access this information as long as the user doesn't restrict access through their facebook account.

b) will it be possible for example via a service application to authenticate with the same app id as the mobile app, and hence be able to collect data from the facebook users who authenticated with the app?

The purpose of my question is, that I would like do some analysis on the users using the iphone app, but I don't want the app to first download the information from facebook, and then pass it on to my service for analysis.

If the above is possible, could anyone please guide me in the direction of what it is that I need to do? Perhaps links to tutorials that describes this setup, og simply tell me the right facebook terminology that I'm looking for to achive this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit late and you may have already picked a service. I have been using [Parse.com](https://www.parse.com/tutorials)
 (tutorial site). They're very good. They have SDKs and sample code for many platforms a RESTful service for others.

They have recently been acquired by FaceBook, and already have strong links to Facebook's SDK.